# Selenium cannot locate Drop down located within modal

Tags: c#, css, selenium

I'm trying to select a value from the drop down 'ddl_settpymtaction' but selenium cannot locate it within the modal that resides in.

CSS:

[image: CSS]

Selenium code

```
 driver.FindElementById("btn_SettlementNew").Click();
        var Action = driver.FindElementById("ddl_SettPymtAction");
        var SelectElement2 = new SelectElement(Action);
        SelectElement2.SelectByValue("EFT");
```

Answer (score 0):

In selenium you should **ALWAYS** add some delay when performing *async* operations (such as a modal which loaded with animations + ajax calls)

**Why?** To get your page a chance to render itself and let selenium wait for the right time to inspect the page (after being rendered with the required elements)

Comment: i added a delay but selenium still cannot find it

Comment: that is because *name* is not *id*.. you are using `FindElementById` and this element has no id.. you can add an id in your dialog select element and then use it properly